# Is a thread started by a daemon thread also a daemon thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

I'm currently working with daemon threads in Java. Is a thread started by a daemon thread a daemon thread itself too? I personally think it is, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by default, any thread created from a daemon thread is also a daemon thread.

In any case, you can always test this, very easily - with [`isDaemon()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isDaemon%28%29).

Comment: Ok, thx! If fixed it with adding setDaemon(false) to the threads it was supposed to start.
I've used it for the command line interpreter of my server, so that, when the server is stopped (most important thread), the daemon stops too.

Answer (score -1):

yes we can make the hierarchy of daemon thread one belongs to other..........

Answer (score -1):

If the thread created by the daemon thread by default he is daemon thread.

On the contrary if the thread created by the user thread , he is user thread.

More on my video about [Daemon threads](https://youtu.be/OQLRiZwnXUM).